# clickonce installer - extra startmenu item

Tags: c#, clickonce

I basicly wanna do this because it seems the clickonce installer cache sometimes gets corrupted or applications data files get corrupted.
So basicly what i want to do is have a extra start menu thats either calls a batch file or my app with a command line args.

Was hoping this could be done with clickonce, simply because i do alot of updates to the app. It has a very small install base ( less then 50 ppl ) and 2 click to publish is nice.

Comment: If data "gets corrupted", find out what is going wrong and prevent it. Don't break things and try to "fix" the wreckage.

Comment: If this was a comersial/public product i agree with you. But its a app for a internal group of gamers. Spending forever debuging / testing is not worth it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add additional start menu short-cuts with ClickOnce beyond the standard application and help shortcuts.  You *can* do whatever you want in the code of your application as long as the user has the security privilege to do it.  So you could just write code to create a shortcut.

What are you going to have your shortcut do?  What's wrong with just removing the application with Add/Remove Programs?

Comment: Removing via Add/Remove programs does not clean application data. Nor does it clear thee clickonce cache.